# Do I Generate a :primary_key to Create Headers in Table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, primary-key, tabular, scaffold

**Rails g scaffold Quantified {type:string** (i.e. average or instance) **name:string metric:string} result:decimal date:date**

Do I use a :primary_key to help generate the below table? I put the main components in the above brackets.

I want the bracketed data types to be the headers of the table, then whenever a user submits a new _form  that includes an existing **type, name, & metric** (i.e. primary_keys?) then the _form would add a new column reflecting the **result & date** to the preexisting row.

[image]

Here's what a similar table looks like live on my blog: http://www.anthonygalli.com/quantify/

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but rails will generate an `id` column to be used as a primary key.

Comment: I couldn't figure out what primary_key does from what I read. I thought it would help me specify certain data types as being associated with other date types to help me create the table above from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No :primary_key was needed I used scope in the rb file instead.